# silex logout page NotFoundHttpException

Tags: security, session, symfony, routes, silex

I am learning silex and going through the docs and am having trouble with the logout for the security provider. The login is working fine and the forms are generated. When I go to admin/logout I get an exception.

> NotFoundHttpException: Unable to find the controller for path "/admin/logout". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?

My understanding of the docs is that the route should be made magically. by the security provider. http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html#adding-a-logout

```
$app->register(new SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
        'security.firewalls' => array(
            'unsecured' => array(
                'anonymous' => true
            ),
            'admin' => array(
                'pattern' => '^/admin',
                'http' => true,
                //use forms for the login insetad
                'form' => array(
                    'login_path' => '/login', 
                    'check_path' => '/admin/login_check'
                ),
                'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/admin/logout'),
                'users' => array(
                    // raw password is foo
                    'admin' => array('ROLE_ADMIN', '5FZ2Z8QIkA7UTZ4BYkoC+GsReLf569mSKDsfods6LYQ8t+a8EW9oaircfMpmaLbPBh4FOBiiFyLfuZmTSUwzZg=='),
                ),
            ),
        )
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just needed to remove

```
'unsecured' => array(
    'anonymous' => true
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an answer but I cannot comment on your answer either so will have to do it like this.

Anyway removing the unsecured firewall does not fix the problem, atleast for me. Isn't the unsecure firewall needed for accessing the login screen. If I'm wrong I'll create a separate question.